# Why heroku does not run my procfile processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, foreman

When I run `foreman start` on localhost all the process inside the Procfile run normally:

#Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
sqs_converted: bundle exec rake sqs:listen_converted
sqs_failed: bundle exec rake sqs:listen_failed
```

---

```
$ foreman start

13:52:07 sqs_failed.1     | started with pid 3521
13:52:07 web.1            | started with pid 3518
13:52:07 sqs_converted.1  | started with pid 3520
13:52:07 resque.1         | started with pid 3519
```

But when I deploy to heroku and run `heroku ps` all I have running is a web.1 instance

```
=== web: `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: up for 8m
```

Can't figure out what is happening...
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still need to scale your processes with `heroku ps:scale resque=1 sqs_convert=1 sqs_failed=1`. You can read all about scaling your processes and the commands you can use in [Scaling your process formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling) in the Heroku docs.

Comment: Hmmm, I ran this command and it work! But still want this to run when deploy. Is possible?

Comment: You only need to scale processes the first time I believe. When redeploying process count will be kept.

Comment: can I have these processes without have to pay extra for each one?

Comment: For every additional process that is running on Heroku the clock is counting: it's five cents per hour I believe, which totals to about $35 per month and process. You get 750 free dyno hours though which covers your first dyno. Any additional usage you'll have to pay for. Maybe there is a way for you to make have only one worker process doing all the tasks that need to be done.